# How to set date and array of dates in a file and struct

Tags: go, goroutine

I have to save a record per request after 60s which I have to save to my appsettings.json the records like for example

```
09/13/2019 11:38 AM: request count last 60s : 4
09/13/2019 12:40 PM: request count last 60s : 6
```

In my struct I set this as

```
// Appsettings struct
    Appsettings struct {
        Requests []Requests `request`
    }

    // Requests struct
    Requests struct {
        RequestDate string      `requestDate`
        Datas       []time.Time `datas`
    }
```

My goal is to count the number of request after 60s and count the request.

If you have any suggestion how can I display this

```
09/13/2019 11:38 AM: request count last 60s : 4
09/13/2019 12:40 PM: request count last 60s : 6
```

and store this in my file.

Comment: You are aware that that is not json, and that saving that format into a "json" file is misleading. Using ".txt" seems to me more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Requests struct {
    RequestDate string      `requestDate`
    Datas       []time.Time `datas`
}

type Appsettings struct {
    Requests []Requests `request`
}

var appsettings Appsettings

func addRequest(requestTime time.Time) {
    timeString := requestTime.Format("01/02/2006 03:04 PM")

    requestFound := false
    for key, request := range appsettings.Requests {
        if request.RequestDate == timeString {
            requestFound = true
            request.Datas = append(request.Datas, requestTime)
            appsettings.Requests[key] = request
        }
    }

    if requestFound == false {
        newRequest := Requests{
            RequestDate: timeString,
            Datas: make([]time.Time, 0),
        }
        newRequest.Datas = append(newRequest.Datas, requestTime)
        appsettings.Requests = append(appsettings.Requests, newRequest)
    }
}

func printRequests() {
    for _, request := range appsettings.Requests {
        fmt.Printf("%s: request count last 60s : %d\n", request.RequestDate, len(request.Datas))
    }
}

func main() {
    appsettings = Appsettings{}
    appsettings.Requests = make([]Requests, 0)

    requestTime, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2006-09-13T11:04:00Z")
    addRequest(requestTime)

    requestTime, _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2006-09-13T15:04:00Z")
    addRequest(requestTime)

    requestTime, _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2006-09-13T15:04:59Z")
    addRequest(requestTime)

    requestTime, _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2006-09-13T15:05:01Z")
    addRequest(requestTime)

    printRequests()
}
```

Reproduce this output:

```
09/13/2006 11:04 AM: request count last 60s : 1
09/13/2006 03:04 PM: request count last 60s : 2
09/13/2006 03:05 PM: request count last 60s : 1
```

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/XqyhScHDW8R